# What language to use for AI / Machine Learning Project

Tags: function, functional-programming, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I'm coding a personal project that is intended to have a class or object that can evolve, let's call it "Robot." Robot needs to be able, given a command, to create classes, fields, and functions, and the ability to write logic into those objects for their operation (but do this all generically).

To do this, I've found myself programming classes such as if statements and while statements. Then I have an object which represents a function type called "Method" take any number of those logical statements as parameters for it's own execution logic. I feel like what I am doing is redundant or that I am accidentally writing a programming language in the process of making this machine that can write it's own code.

I realize this is a vague description. I am learning the requirements as I develop it, but I can answer any questions that will help explain. My main question is if anyone recognizes this process and can identify it (or if it is redundant), and if a language other than Java is specifically suited to this type of project.

I also need to be able to pass functions as parameters (currently using an interface Executable to do this).

EDIT: I have decided to proceed in C, since pointers and function pointers provide functionality that I need and cannot do in Java.

Comment: **Robot needs to be able, given a command, to create classes, fields, and functions, and the ability to write logic into those objects for their operation (but do this all generically).**   Sorry can't help you. It sounds like `Robot` is after my job!

Comment: >"I have decided to proceed in C, since pointers and function pointers provide functionality that I need and cannot do in Java." That sounds good, although functors in C++ (or better lambdas in C++11), would be a safer an easier choice in my opinion

Comment: Yes, after continued research, I am thinking C# since it supports serialization, function pointers (delegates), and function overloading. C++ is ugly, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Peter Novig has written many books on the subject of AI and he made a [retrospect page](http://norvig.com/Lisp-retro.html) about LISP status in AI where he wonders if Lisp is still the tool for the job.

A dynamic and extensible language like one of the Lisp dialects are good at making the right tool for the job, but I remember Peter Norvig shed some light on what [AI programmers choose today](http://norvig.com/Lisp-retro.html) (or when he wrote it). Perhaps you can do the google searched he did to see if it's changed.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers have suggested Lisp (rightfully), I suggest to have a look at Clojure programming language as a foundation for your project.

Clojure is a modern Lisp dialect that runs on the JVM. This means that your project will run on a battle-tested runtime and you have access to a huge ecosystem of libraries.

> I also need to be able to pass functions as parameters (currently using an interface Executable to do this).

If you use Clojure, you will have exactly what you want plus a ton of features.

> Robot needs to be able, given a command, to create classes, fields, and functions, and the ability to write logic into those objects for their operation (but do this all generically)

Clojure will exactly help you in this area.